# Trying to Fetch only multiple column from select query where status column with error code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm trying to fetch only specific columns(uri,hostheader) from an Athena query where the status column is like 404.

When I execute the query I get the output for uri and hostheader unable to fetch the results for status 404 with the below query.

```
select
        uri,
        hostheader
from
        accesslogs
where
        CAST(status AS VARCHAR) like '%404%'
```

Comment: Whats the exact error you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error, but also not getting output for 404 from status column using like 404.

Comment: Which service are the logs from?

Comment: It's AWS Cloudfront access logs.

Comment: CloudFront access logs have status as an integer. Therefore it should just be where status = 404

Comment: Tried select uri,  hostheader from accesslogs where status = 404; but still not getting the status column with 404.

Comment: Can you try changing the status to another number, just to check? Or remove the where condition and find an example status that should work

Comment: I tried changing the status to 200, still no luck.

Comment: And without the where condition?

Comment: Yes, without where condition I am able to get uri, hostheader columns.

Comment: Add the status column too to check its value

Comment: I tired with select uri, hostheader, status from accesslogs. I am getting the output for all status.

Comment: Example of one of the outputs. To see the structure

Comment: uri                                 uriqa                hostheader                 status
/doucment/10180           -                members.xxxxx.com        200

Comment: Hmm, so where status = 200 won’t return that record? That seems really odd

Comment: This query worked select uri, status, hostheader from accesslogs where status = 404; Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to not cast as varchar and instead use the native int type

select
        uri,
        hostheader
from
        accesslogs
where
        status = 404